# How to calculate the total value the sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two sets of sliders on my page. One set has four sliders and another set has six sliders. These two sets can be seen when you toggle between 4cos and 6cos on the top left side of my page. I want to calculate the total value of each set of sliders independently and display the total as an alert when I click the Validate button on my page. I am unable to explain properly. Please ask me if you have questions. Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ApnUm/5.

Here is my code.

HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.nouislider.css"/>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="att.framework.css"/> -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.nouislider.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cos_buttonsDiv">
<div class="cos4Button btn_bgColor">4 CoS</div>
<div class="cos6Button">6 CoS</div>

<div class="ConfigureCos4Header">
<div>CoS1 is dedicated to Real Time traffic.</div>
<div>Please select a value from 0% to 100%</div>
</div>
<div class="ConfigureCos6Header">
<div>Real Time Traffic is dedicated to CoS1.</div>
<div>The available values diff based on the CoS Package</div>
</div>

</div>

<!-- 4 sliders Div-->

<div class="Configure4Div">
<div class="ConfigureCos4">
<div>CoS 1 Real Time</div>
    <div class="example" id="cos4_darkBlue">
    <div class="slider-connect" id="cos4_slider1"> 
    </div>
    <div id="cos4_field1"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="plusMinusDiv">
    <div class="minusButton"><span style="line-height:25px;font-size:33px;padding-left:11px;">-</span></div>
    <div class="plusButton"><span class="icon-plus" style="line-height:28px;font-size:16px;padding-left:7px;">+</span></div>
</div>
</div>  


<div class="ConfigureCos_4">
    <div class="slide_Div">

    <div class="example" id="cos4_green">
    <div class="slider-connect" id="cos4_slider2">
    </div>
    <div id="cos4_field2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="plusMinusDiv">
    <div class="minusButton"><span style="line-height:25px;font-size:33px;padding-left:11px;">-</span></div>
    <div class="plusButton"><span class="icon-plus" style="line-height:28px;font-size:16px;padding-left:7px;">+</span></div>
</div>
</div>


    <div class="slide_Div">
    <div class="example" id="cos4_pink">
    <div class="slider-connect" id="cos4_slider3">
    </div>
      <div id="cos4_field3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="plusMinusDiv">
    <div class="minusButton"><span style="line-height:25px;font-size:33px;padding-left:11px;">-</span></div>
    <div class="plusButton"><span class="icon-plus" style="line-height:28px;font-size:16px;padding-left:7px;">+</span></div>
</div>
</div>

     <div class="slide_Div">
    <div class="example" id="cos4_orange">
    <div class="slider-connect" id="cos4_slider4"></div>
    <div id="cos4_field4"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="plusMinusDiv">
    <div class="minusButton"><span style="line-height:25px;font-size:33px;padding-left:11px;">-</span></div>
    <div class="plusButton"><span class="icon-plus" style="line-height:28px;font-size:16px;padding-left:7px;">+</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- 4 sliders Div close-->

<!-- 6 sliders Div-->
<div class="Configure6Div">
<div class="ConfigureCos6">
<div>CoS 1 Real Time</div>
    <div class="example" id="Cos6_Darkblue">
    <div class="slider-connect" id="cos6_slider1"></div>
    <div id="cos6_field1"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="plusMinusDiv">
    <div class="minusButton"><span style="line-height:25px;font-size:33px;padding-left:11px;">-</span></div>
    <div class="plusButton"><span class="icon-plus" style="line-height:28px;font-size:16px;padding-left:7px;">+</span></div>
</div>
</div>

    <div class="ConfigureCos_6">
     <div class="slide_Div">
    <div class="example"id="Cos6_lightblue" >
    <div class="slider-connect" id="cos6_slider2"></div>
    <div id="cos6_field2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="plusMinusDiv">
    <div class="minusButton"><span style="line-height:25px;font-size:33px;padding-left:11px;">-</span></div>
    <div class="plusButton"><span class="icon-plus" style="line-height:28px;font-size:16px;padding-left:7px;">+</span></div>
</div>
</div>

     <div class="slide_Div">
    <div class="example" id="Cos6_green">
    <div class="slider-connect" id="cos6_slider3"></div>
    <div id="cos6_field3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="plusMinusDiv">
    <div class="minusButton"><span style="line-height:25px;font-size:33px;padding-left:11px;">-</span></div>
    <div class="plusButton"><span class="icon-plus" style="line-height:28px;font-size:16px;padding-left:7px;">+</span></div>
</div>
</div>

     <div class="slide_Div">
    <div class="example" id="Cos6_pink">
    <div class="slider-connect" id="cos6_slider4"></div>
      <div id="cos6_field4"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="plusMinusDiv">
    <div class="minusButton"><span style="line-height:25px;font-size:33px;padding-left:11px;">-</span></div>
    <div class="plusButton"><span class="icon-plus" style="line-height:28px;font-size:16px;padding-left:7px;">+</span></div>
</div>
</div>

     <div class="slide_Div">
    <div class="example" id="Cos6_gold">
    <div class="slider-connect" id="cos6_slider5"></div>
    <div id="cos6_field5"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="plusMinusDiv">
    <div class="minusButton"><span style="line-height:25px;font-size:33px;padding-left:11px;">-</span></div>
    <div class="plusButton"><span class="icon-plus" style="line-height:28px;font-size:16px;padding-left:7px;">+</span></div>
</div>
</div>

     <div class="slide_Div">
    <div class="example" id="Cos6_Darkpink">
    <div class="slider-connect" id="cos6_slider6"></div>
    <div id="cos6_field6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="plusMinusDiv">
    <div class="minusButton"><span style="line-height:25px;font-size:33px;padding-left:11px;">-</span></div>
    <div class="plusButton"><span class="icon-plus" style="line-height:28px;font-size:16px;padding-left:7px;">+</span></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="fixed-size-square">
    <span class="cos_validate_button" id="mybtn"><button  id="validate_btn" class="btn btn-val btn-small">Validate</button></span>
</div>
<hr style="border-bottom:0px solid #D3D3D2; width:1100px; margin-top:49px;">
<!--<div class="callout bottom">The Selection is not a valid profile for the CoS Package. Please select another profile.</div>-->
<table width="100%">
<tr>
 <td><div class="cos_buttons">      
            <span class="cos_review_button"><button id="review_btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-small">Review</button></span>&nbsp;
            <span class="cos_cancel_button"><a class="cancel-redirectChangeIP" href="javascript:void(0)"><button class="btn btn-small cancelButtonChangeIP">Cancel</button></a></span>
        </div></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<!-- 6 sliders Div close-->

<!-- <script src="att.framework.js"></script> -->
<script>

</script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

CSS


/* Functional styling;
 * These styles are required for noUiSlider to function.
 * You don't need to change these rules to apply your design.
 */
.noUi-target,
.noUi-target * {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-touch-action: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.noUi-base {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.noUi-origin {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.noUi-handle {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.noUi-stacking .noUi-handle {
/* This class is applied to the lower origin when
   its values is > 50%. */
    z-index: 10;
}
.noUi-stacking + .noUi-origin {
/* Fix stacking order in IE7, which incorrectly
   creates a new context for the origins. */
    *z-index: -1;
}
.noUi-state-tap .noUi-origin {
-webkit-transition: left 0.3s, top 0.3s;
    transition: left 0.3s, top 0.3s;
}
.noUi-state-drag * {
    cursor: inherit !important;
}

/* Slider size and handle placement;
 */
.noUi-horizontal {
    height: 18px;
}
.noUi-horizontal .noUi-handle {
    width: 34px;
    height: 28px;
    left: -17px;
    top: -6px;
}
.noUi-horizontal.noUi-extended {
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.noUi-horizontal.noUi-extended .noUi-origin  {
    right: -15px;
}
.noUi-vertical {
    width: 18px;
}
.noUi-vertical .noUi-handle {
    width: 28px;
    height: 34px;
    left: -6px;
    top: -17px;
}
.noUi-vertical.noUi-extended {
    padding: 15px 0;
}
.noUi-vertical.noUi-extended .noUi-origin  {
    bottom: -15px;
}

/* Styling;
 */
.noUi-background {
    background: #FAFAFA;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #f0f0f0;
}
.noUi-connect {
    background: #3FB8AF;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(51,51,51,0.45);
-webkit-transition: background 450ms;
    transition: background 450ms;
}
.noUi-origin {
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.noUi-target {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #F0F0F0, 0 3px 6px -5px #BBB;
}
.noUi-target.noUi-connect {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(51,51,51,0.45), 0 3px 6px -5px #BBB;
}

/* Handles and cursors;
 */
.noUi-dragable {
    cursor: w-resize;
}
.noUi-vertical .noUi-dragable {
    cursor: n-resize;
}
.noUi-handle {
    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #FFF;
    cursor: default;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #FFF,
                inset 0 1px 7px #EBEBEB,
                0 3px 6px -3px #BBB;
}
.noUi-active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #FFF,
                inset 0 1px 7px #DDD,
                0 3px 6px -3px #BBB;
}

/* Handle stripes;
 */
.noUi-handle:before,
.noUi-handle:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 14px;
    width: 1px;
    background: #E8E7E6;
    left: 14px;
    top: 6px;
}
.noUi-handle:after {
    left: 17px;
}
.noUi-vertical .noUi-handle:before,
.noUi-vertical .noUi-handle:after {
    width: 14px;
    height: 1px;
    left: 6px;
    top: 14px;
}
.noUi-vertical .noUi-handle:after {
    top: 17px;
}

/* Disabled state;
 */
[disabled].noUi-connect,
[disabled] .noUi-connect {
    background: #B8B8B8;
}
[disabled] .noUi-handle {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
.cos_validate_button{float:right;margin-right:48px;margin-left:48px;padding-top:30px;margin-bottom:20px;}
.cos_cancel_button{float:left;margin-left:400px;margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:100px;}
.cos_review_button{float:right;margin-right:400px;margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:100px;}
.btn{position:relative;display:inline-block;-moz-background-clip:padding-box;-webkit-background-clip:padding-box;background-clip:padding-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;min-width:100px;padding:12px 30px;padding:1.2rem 2.9rem;border:none;border-radius:6px;background-color:#666666;background-image:none;color:#ffffff;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;text-transform:capitalize;text-shadow:none;white-space:nowrap;font-size:18px;line-height:18px;cursor:pointer;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;-o-user-select:none;user-select:none;-webkit-transition:background-color 0.3s ease-out;-moz-transition:background-color 0.3s ease-out;transition:background-color 0.3s ease-out;}
.btn:hover,.btn:focus{background-color:#bbbbbb;color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;}
.btn.active,.btn:active{background-color:#666666;color:#bbbbbb;-webkit-transition:background-color 0;-moz-transition:background-color 0;transition:background-color 0;}
.btn{border-top-color:#000000 !important;}
.btn-primary{color:#ffffff;background-color:#067ab4;border-color:none;}
.btn-primary:hover,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary{color:#ffffff;background-color:#199ddf;border-color:none;}
.btn-primary:active,.btn-primary.active{color:#ffffff;background-color:#067ab4;background-image:none;}
.btn-primary:focus{color:#ffffff;background-color:#199ddf;}
.btn-primary.btn-dark-bkgd{color:#ffffff;background-color:#023187;border-color:none;}
.btn-primary.btn-dark-bkgd:hover,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary.btn-dark-bkgd{color:#ffffff;background-color:#014b9d;border-color:none;}
.btn-primary.btn-dark-bkgd:active,.btn-primary.btn-dark-bkgd.active{color:#067ab4;background-color:#6aafd2;background-image:none;}
.btn-primary.btn-dark-bkgd:focus{color:#ffffff;background-color:#199ddf;}
.btn-small{padding:8px 20px;font-size:18px;line-height:21.6px;min-width:60px;width:120px;font-family:clearviewatt;height:41px;padding-top:9px;}
.btn-val{color:#ffffff;background-color:#067ab4;border-color:none;}
.btn-val:hover,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-val{color:#ffffff;background-color:#199ddf;border-color:none;}
.btn-val:active,.btn-val.active{color:#ffffff;background-color:#067ab4;background-image:none;}
.btn-val:focus{color:#ffffff;background-color:#199ddf;}
.btn-val.btn-dark-bkgd{color:#ffffff;background-color:#023187;border-color:none;}
.btn-val.btn-dark-bkgd:hover,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-val.btn-dark-bkgd{color:#ffffff;background-color:#014b9d;border-color:none;}
.btn-val.btn-dark-bkgd:active,.btn-val.btn-dark-bkgd.active{color:#067ab4;background-color:#6aafd2;background-image:none;}
.btn-val.btn-dark-bkgd:focus{color:#ffffff;background-color:#199ddf;}

.fixed-size-square {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: table;
    width: 200px;
    height: 600px;
  }
.fixed-size-square span {
    margin-top: 500px;
 }

Javascript/jQuery

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.ConfigureCos6Header').hide();

$('.cos6Button').click(function(){
$('.cos6Button').addClass('btn_bgColor');
$('.cos4Button').removeClass('btn_bgColor');
$('.Configure6Div').show();
$('.Configure4Div').hide();
$('.ConfigureCos6Header').show();
$('.ConfigureCos4Header').hide();
});

$('.cos4Button').click(function(){
$('.cos4Button').addClass('btn_bgColor');
$('.cos6Button').removeClass('btn_bgColor');
$('.ConfigureCos4Header').show();
$('.ConfigureCos6Header').hide();
$('.Configure6Div').hide();
$('.Configure4Div').show();
});


var toolTip = $.Link({
    target: '-tooltip-'
});
/* cos4 Sliders*/
$("#cos4_slider1").noUiSlider({
    start: 40,
    connect: "lower",
    range: {
      'min': 0,
      'max': 100
    },
    serialization: {
        lower: [ $.Link({
                target: $("#cos4_field1")
            }),
            toolTip
            ]
    },

});

$("#cos4_slider2").noUiSlider({
    start: 80,
    connect: "lower",
    range: {
      'min': 0,
      'max': 100
    },
    serialization: {
        lower: [ $.Link({
                target: $("#cos4_field2")
            }),
            toolTip
            ]
    },

});

$("#cos4_slider3").noUiSlider({
    start: 20,
    connect: "lower",
    range: {
      'min': 0,
      'max': 100
    },
    serialization: {
        lower: [ $.Link({
                target: $("#cos4_field3")
            }),
            toolTip
            ]
    },

});


$("#cos4_slider4").noUiSlider({
    start: 60,
    connect: "lower",
    range: {
      'min': 0,
      'max': 100
    },
    serialization: {
        lower: [ $.Link({
                target: $("#cos4_field4")
            }),
            toolTip
            ]

    },

});
/* cos4 Sliders close*/


/* cos6 Sliders*/


$("#cos6_slider1").noUiSlider({
    start: 60,
    connect: "lower",
    range: {
      'min': 0,
      'max': 100
    },
    serialization: {
        lower: [ $.Link({
                target: $("#cos6_field1")
            }),
            toolTip
            ]
    },

});


$("#cos6_slider2").noUiSlider({
    start: 17,
    connect: "lower",
    range: {
      'min': 0,
      'max': 100
    },
    serialization: {
        lower: [ $.Link({
                target: $("#cos6_field2")
            }),
            toolTip
            ]
    },

});

$("#cos6_slider3").noUiSlider({
    start: 15,
    connect: "lower",
    range: {
      'min': 0,
      'max': 100
    },
    serialization: {
        lower: [ $.Link({
                target: $("#cos6_field3")
            }),
            toolTip
            ]

    },

});

$("#cos6_slider4").noUiSlider({
    start: 20,
    connect: "lower",
    range: {
      'min': 0,
      'max': 100
    },
    serialization: {
        lower: [ $.Link({
                target: $("#cos6_field4")
            }),
            toolTip
            ]
    },

});
$("#cos6_slider5").noUiSlider({
    start: 20,
    connect: "lower",
    range: {
      'min': 0,
      'max': 100
    },
    serialization: {
        lower: [ $.Link({
                target: $("#cos6_field5")
            }),
            toolTip
            ]
    },

});


$("#cos6_slider6").noUiSlider({
    start: 28,
    connect: "lower",
    range: {
      'min': 0,
      'max': 100
    },
    serialization: {
        lower: [ $.Link({
                target: $("#cos6_field6")
            }),
            toolTip
            ]
    },

});
/* cos6 Sliders close*/
$('#review_btn').removeClass('btn-primary');                            
        $('.cos_validate_button').click(function(){
            alert(toolTip);

            });

});
```

Comment: By any chance can you reduce your code to a bare minimum example?

Comment: I tried to reduce the code but its causing other problems. Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ApnUm/1/ but its not working I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
$('.cos_validate_button').click(function(){
    var total6 =   parseFloat($("#cos6_slider1").val()) +
        parseFloat($("#cos6_slider2").val()) +
        parseFloat($("#cos6_slider3").val()) +
        parseFloat($("#cos6_slider4").val()) +
        parseFloat($("#cos6_slider5").val()) +
        parseFloat($("#cos6_slider6").val());
    var total4 = parseFloat($("#cos4_slider1").val()) +
        parseFloat($("#cos4_slider2").val()) +
        parseFloat($("#cos4_slider3").val()) +
        parseFloat($("#cos4_slider4").val());
    var total = total6+total4;
    alert("total 6: "+total6+"\ntotal 4: "+total4+"\ntotal: "+total);

    });
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vk562/2/)